# sqoop import teradata to hive - CommandNeedRetryException

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm trying to import data from Teradata to hive using below Sqoop command:

```
sqoop import \
--connect ${connect} \
--username ${usr} \
--password ${pwd} \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
--table ${tblname} \
--hive-import \
--hive-database ${db} \
--hive-table ${dist_tbl};
```

See error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/CommandNeedRetryException
    at com.teradata.connector.common.tool.ConfigurationMappingUtils.importConfigurationMapping(ConfigurationMappingUtils.java:300)
    at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataSqoopImportHelper.runJob(TeradataSqoopImportHelper.java:360)
    at org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager.importTable(TeradataConnManager.java:504)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:497)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.CommandNeedRetryException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: You may want to add more information to help someone be able to answer your question. I *assume* the question was how to prevent this exception?

Comment: hi user2738962, sorry I'm getting burned-out with this issue on sqoop. I am trying to import data from teradata to hive using the below command:

sqoop import \
--connect ${connect} \
--username ${usr} \
--password ${pwd} \
--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager \
--table ${tblname} \
--hive-import \
--hive-database ${db} \
--hive-table ${dist_tbl};

Thanks

Comment: Can you remove `--hive-database ${db}` command and try `--hive-table your_hive_db.your_hive_tbl`

Comment: Hi Matt, yes I did.but it's still not working..

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing that this question is still not answered.

The answer is simple :

replace "--connection-manager org.apache.sqoop.teradata.TeradataConnManager" with "--driver 'com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'". This will solve the issue